# get values from existing timezone, MomentJS

Tags: datetime, momentjs

I have a timestamp by momentjs say 2021-10-03T14:08:14.249Z, how can I get use this timestamp to get a date, time, and all the other formats using momentjs?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out there is an option for that. `moment.parseZone(timestamp)`